Is there a simpler proof for this simple geometrical result? (An equilateral triangle contains three congruent circles, prove two lengths are equal.)
In equilateral $\triangle ABC$, $D$ is on $AB$, $E$ is on $AC$, and the incircles of $\triangle ADE$, $\triangle DBE$ and $\triangle EBC$ are congruent.


Prove that $BD=DE$.

I asked this question on MSE and it received a few solutions, but they all seem unnecessarily complicated, given the simplicity of the result. Is there a simpler proof?
(For examples of the level of simplicity that I am hoping for, see answers to my recent geometrical puzzles here and here. Maybe I am overly optimistic.)
Where the diagram comes from
Inspired by this Sangaku problem, I created this diagram. It looked like $BD=DE$, so I used a computer to investigate, and they were the same to many decimal places.

Perhaps, a better solution can be found if you can disclose how this fact was discovered.

@IosifPinelis Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited.

Here is a solution, which seems simpler than the existing ones.
Without loss of generality, $AB=1$.
Let $x:=BD\in(0,1)$ and $y:=CE\in(0,1)$. Enumerate the circles by $1,2,3$ from the topmost one to the one at the bottom. Let $A_1,A_2,A_3$, $P_1,P_2,P_3$, and $r_1,r_2,r_3$ be the areas, perimeters, and inradii of the corresponding triangles, so that
$$r_j=2A_j/P_j$$
for $j=1,2,3$. Clearly,
$$A_3=yA,\quad A_1=(1-x)(1-y)A,\quad A_2=\frac x{1-x}\,A_1=x(1-y)A,$$
where $A=\sqrt3/4$ is the area of the triangle $ABC$.
Also, by the cosine rule,
$$BE=\sqrt{1+y^2-y},\quad DE=\sqrt{(1 - x)^2 + (1 - y)^2 - (1 - x) (1 - y)}, \tag{10}\label{10} $$
and then
$$P_1=1 - x + 1 - y +DE,\quad P_2=x+BE+DE,\quad P_3=1+y+DE. \tag{20}\label{20}$$
So, the equations $r_1=r_2=r_3$ are two simple algebraic equations with the two unknowns, $x$ and $y$. Solving them can be done by squaring to get rid of square roots.
Indeed, note that the expressions of the $P_j$'s in \eqref{20} are linear in $BE$ and $DE$. So, the equations $r_1=r_2=r_3$ can be rewritten as linear equations in $BE$ and $DE$. Solving these two equations for $BE$ and $DE$, we get expressions for $BE$ and $DE$ that are rational in $x,y$. Equating the latter expressions for $BE$ and $DE$ with their respective expressions in \eqref{10} and then squaring both sides of the resulting equations, we get equations of the form $P(x,y)=0=Q(x,y)$, where
$$P(x,y):=20 x^2 y^2-20 x^2 y+4 x^2-12 x y^2+4 x y+4 x+3 y-3,$$
$$Q(x,y):=-4 x^3 y+4 x^3+4 x^2 y^2-4 x^2 y-4 x^2+12 x y^2-7 x y+5 x-3 y;$$
these polynomials were obtained by factoring out $y$ and $(1-x)(1-y)$ from the respective initial versions of $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$.
Let $R_1(y)$ and $R_2(x)$ denote, respectively, the resultants of the polynomials $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ wrt $x$ and wrt $y$, so that
\begin{align}
R_1(y)&=-\frac{12}{25} (3 y-2)^4 (8 y-5) \left(5 y+a^2-2 a-1\right) \\ 
&\times\left(a^2-2 a+2-i \sqrt{6} \sqrt{2 a^2+a+4}-10y\right) \\ 
&\times\left(a^2-2 a+2+i \sqrt{6} \sqrt{2 a^2+a+4}-10 y\right),
\end{align}
\begin{align}
R_2(x)&=\frac{1}{50} (3-2 x)^4 (1-x) x^2  \left(3 a^2-a+2-10 x\right) \\
&\times\left(20 x+3 a^2-a-4-i b\right) \\ 
&\times\left(20 x+3 a^2-a-4+i b\right),
\end{align}
where
$$a:=2^{1/3},\quad b:=2^{1/6} \sqrt{3} \left(a^2+a-1\right) \sqrt{2 a^2+a+4}.$$
So, the only root of $R_2(x)$ in $(0,1)$ is
$$x_*:=\frac{1}{10} \left(2-2^{1/3}+3\times 2^{2/3}\right)=0.550\ldots$$
and the only roots of $R_1(y)$ in $(0,1)$ are $5/8$, $2/3$, and
$$y_*:=\frac{1}{5} \left(1+2^{4/3}-2^{2/3}\right)=0.386\ldots.$$
Next,
$$P(x,5/8)=\frac{11}{16} (1-x) (x-18/11),$$
which does not have roots in $(0,1)$, and
$$P(x,2/3)=-\frac{1}{9} (2 x-3)^2,$$
which does not have roots in $(0,1)$ either.
So, the only feasible solution is $(x_*,y_*)$ (which one can easily check to be a solution indeed), and for $(x,y)=(x_*,y_*)$ we do have $$BD=x=\sqrt{(1 - x)^2 + (1 - y)^2 - (1 - x) (1 - y)}=DE.$$

Thank you. It is a nice approach, but I wonder if it is really simpler than the other solutions, if the calculations are done without a computer.

@Dan : I have now explained how to do the calculations "more" manually.
